# Background Color from XIB disappears after add to main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, xib

I created a `widget.xib` where I have my own view, which I would like to add to `main.storyboard`. Class `widget.swift` looks like that:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class Widget: UIView {

var view: UIView!

var nibName: String = "Widget"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup(){

    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    addSubview(view)    
}


func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! UIView

    return view
}
} //end class
```

and my widget's View looks like that:

[image: Xib File]

nad now, when I open `main.storyboard`, I add view to this storyboard, and then in this new view I set the class as `Widget` I see all labels, buttons but I don't see background color. Why?
Quick look at my main.storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: OK, I have it. So it is a little bit strange, but background color comes back when I launch this app in simulator.

Comment: have you tried purging your DerivedData? or doing a clean rebuild (Cmd + Shift + K) then build as per normal. On top of that Xcode isn't "layer backed" so often enough visual reps in IB aren't always up to par...